# can I set my location for careers advert

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs, advertising, location

The careers advert in the sidebar, you know the one - **more jobs near (your location)**

I understand that it is detecting my location somehow, however it seems to think I'm based in London when I'm in Dundee, Scotland. Even if it were showing other jobs throughout Scotland, it'd be more relevant.

I have my location set in my profile on both Stack Overflow and Careers, but it doesn't seem to use this.

Is there a way I can override the location it's detecting?

Comment: I'm not in London either, but all the jobs it shows me are (Or in the US)

Comment: It's only a 6 hour train journey... (then commute to the office building) you can do that each day surely? :-)

Comment: So I assume the lack of an answer means that this isn't possible at the moment? Should this be tagged as a feature request then?

Comment: I have the same problem; because all remote offices go through a central proxy in NJ it assumes I need a job down there. That's a few states off from my actual location and no help in a job search.

Comment: the widget is useless to me unless I can somehow specify closer jobs than the ones is shows me...

Comment: I now have this problem after my company made some proxy server changes overnight. The "jobs near you" widget is showing positions for Dallas, Texas USA which is a six hour drive from my current location :/